# A few questions about installing engineered hardwood

Tags: hardwood-floor

I'm installing engineered hardwood for the first time next week. The wood I've chosen is    Wire Brushed Strand Woven Cocoa Bean 3/8 in. T. x 5-1/5 in. W. x 36.02 in. L. Click Lock Bamboo Flooring (13sq.ft./case) Model # 300011041 (Home Depot)

I'm wondering a few things:

```
What type of tape should I use to join together pieces of underlayment?
What type of nails/staples should I use for installation?
What's the recommended expansion gap?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/bf/bf514ff3-3069-4724-8d3c-07674130b4ca.pdf) for that product which are provided on Home Depot's web site indicate that this floor is intended for either floating or glue-down installation.
As such, no nails or staples are appropriate or necessary.
The instructions also specify a 1/2" expansion gap.

The fact that you're asking about taped underlayment strongly implies that you're not intending to glue it down - so (unless you're planning to go against the manufacturer's recommended installation instructions and nail it anyway) you should be doing a floating installation over the underlayment.

Some underlayment has pre-glued strips along one edge which you use to stick the pieces together, but obviously this doesn't always cover every join, so you'll probably need at least a little tape to finish off.
You should be able to buy this tape along with the underlayment.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the provided manufacturer instructions. It hasn't arrived yet and I'm trying to look ahead.